# strange javascript behaviour onClick on div with cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova

i've setted up a little project...i have some divs, when i click one of this div i want to get its id and for now to display an alert with its id, after that i want to redirect to a page that will get its id and do some stuff..my js is:

```
  function onLoad() {

        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

      //  alert("loaddddddd");
    }

    function reply_click(clicked_id)
    {
       alert(clicked_id);
    }
    function onDeviceReady() {
        //occorrerà rendere dinamica questa ricerca
        //alert("aaa");

        var div = document.getElementById('c1');


        for(var i=1;i<=7;i++){


            var div = document.getElementById('c'+i);

            div.addEventListener("click",reply_click(i));
        }

      }
```

the problem is that when it loop over the div before i click anything it display me all the alerts...and obviusly when i click it doesn't display nothing
thank you

Comment: You need to pass a reference to a function, but here: `div.addEventListener("click",reply_click(i));` you're executing the `reply_click` function, which executes the alert.

Comment: ok now with div.addEventListener("click",function(){reply_click(i)}); it alert when clicked, but Always getting id 8...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1: return a function from `reply_click(n)` that alerts the correct `n`. The `reply_click` function becomes a [closure](http://jondavidjohn.com/javascript-closure-explained-using-events/):

```
function reply_click(clicked_id){
  var id = clicked_id;
  return function(){
    alert( id );
  }
}
function onDeviceReady() {
    for(var i=1;i<=7;i++){
        var div = document.getElementById('c'+i);
        // here the reply_click is called immediately, 
        // but returns another function which is added as event handler
        div.addEventListener("click",reply_click(i));
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g8qfpn7L/

Solution 2: [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) `reply_click` to an object, then alert a property of that object:

```
function reply_click(){
    alert( this.id );
}
function onDeviceReady() {
    for(var i=1;i<=7;i++){
        var div = document.getElementById('c'+i);
        // here we bind reply_click to an object with id property, 
        // and the bound function is called in event handler
        div.addEventListener("click",reply_click.bind({ id : i }));
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g8qfpn7L/1/

Comment: @Lorenzo have you tried the linked demos on jsfiddle?

Comment: yes...now it's working...but is the same thing i wrote before...maybe some error writing :) thank you a lot!!!

Comment: but it is not working if i insert:
 function reply_click(clicked_id){
     
        return function(){
         
         window.location.href("demo.html?clicked="+clicked_id); 
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add an event listener on the document instead? Might be a better option and makes your code simpler.

```
var elements = ["c1","c2","c3"]; //eligible dom elements

//add the event listener just once on the document level
document.addEventListener("click", function(event){
        var targetElement = event.target || event.srcElement;
        if (elements.indexOf(targetElement.id) >= 0)
           reply_click(targetElement.id);
});
```